# flexible css grid tiles

Tags: html, css

I was trying to remove the svg's without altering how the grid works.

The svgs are used to achieve an aspect-ratio of 1 for all tiles.

EDIT: Seems like there is a CSS Solution for this.

simply had to set `aspect-ratio: 1` for my tiles.

This seems to be really new is there another solution for this other than using the svg hack?

```css
body>div {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  min-width: 700px
}

div div {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
  <div><svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This question is not answered. Why did someone close this?

Answer (score 0):

You can scale, maintaining aspect ratio, by fixing the width and height to the same value. One way to do this is to use viewport width or height.

```css
div
{
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: In your example the tiles don't change their size to fill the entire width of the page.

Comment: You were very vague in what the example was doing that you liked. They don't fill the entire width of the page either. Not always. Opening the snippet in your question leaves two tiles with a large portion of white space beside them.

Comment: I probably could have been more specific.